# PHP Explode and Foreach $_POST

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I need to echo as many lines like the following ouput example, depending on the number of Phone numbers coming from my html $_POST:

**The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-879-009**

**Here is another repeating the same number 555-879-009**

**And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-879-009**

*This is my original php:*

```
<htnl>
<body>
<h6>
<br><br>
;*****************************************<br>
;  <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
;*****************************************<br>
<br>

The Phone Number(s) assigned is <?php echo $_POST["number"]; ?> <br>
Here is another repeating the same number <?php echo $_POST["number"]; ?> <br>
And this third line is again, repeating the number <?php echo $_POST["number"]; ?> <br>

</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

**Now I tried using explode and foreach but i got the following result :**

The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-879-009 555-676-999 555-874-333 555-344-775

Here is another repeating the same number 555-879-009 555-676-999 555-874-333 555-344-775

And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-879-009 555-676-999 555-874-333 555-344-775

**What I need is this:**

The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-879-009

Here is another repeating the same number 555-879-009

And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-879-009

The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-676-999

Here is another repeating the same number 555-676-999

And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-676-999

The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-874-333

Here is another repeating the same number 555-874-333

And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-874-333

The Phone Number(s) assigned is 555-344-775

Here is another repeating the same number 555-344-775

And this third line is again, repeating the number 555-344-775

**I need to print as many numbers depending on what is incoming from my html form
here is my php try:**

```
<htnl>
<body>
<h6>
<br><br>
;*****************************************<br>
;  <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
;*****************************************<br>
<br>

 The Phone Number(s) assigned is <?php $number = explode(' ', $_POST['number']);foreach ($number as $varnumber){ echo $varnumber;}?> <br>
Here is another repeating the same number <?php $number = explode(' ', $_POST['number']);foreach ($number as $varnumber){ echo $varnumber;}?> <br>
And this third line is again, repeating the number <?php $number = explode(' ', $_POST['number']);foreach ($number as $varnumber){ echo $varnumber;}?> <br>



</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds to me like you have a multidimensional array. how are you obtaining this array? is it from form submission?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `foreach` loop around the whole block of HTML.

```
<?php
$numbers = explode(' ', $_POST['number']);
foreach ($numbers as $n) { ?>
    The Phone Number(s) assigned is <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    Here is another repeating the same number <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    And this third line is again, repeating the number <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    ?>
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the tip, makes more sense to put the loop around the whole html.

Comment: I copy and paste your code but it is giving me an error ... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Line 17 while there are only 16 ..???

Comment: <html>
<body>
<h6>

<?php
$numbers = explode(' ', $_POST['number']);
foreach ($numbers as $n) { ?>
    The Phone Number(s) assigned is <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    Here is another repeating the same number <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    And this third line is again, repeating the number <?php echo $n; ?> <br>
    ?>
}

</h6>
</body>
</html>
Line 16 is </html> , what could be wrong, I have written the file from scratch a few times... ???

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a semicolon or your braces aren't balanced. Hard to tell from the unreadable code in a comment. But if you're using an intelligent IDE it should be able to help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, you need to surround each grouping of phone number print outs with a foreach statement.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Example using alternate PHP syntax.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php
$phones = explode(' ', $_POST["number"]);

foreach($phones as $phone):?>
The Phone Number(s) assigned is <?php echo $phone ?><br />
Here is another repeating the same number <?php echo $phone ?><br />
And this third line is again, repeating the number <?php echo $phone ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sac, your code while very similar to Barmar's is missing brackets in the Foreach loop? And is your endforeach closing correct?  <?php endforeach; instead of <?php endforeach ?>     Just asking Im very new and confused

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, in PHP, it is best practice to leave out the final closing ?> brackets at the very end of the document. foreach($things as $thing): and endforeach; are together alternative syntax that is easier to follow when interweaving with HTML blocks. Think about a long PHP template file with lots of IF, ELSE, FOREACH control statements and try keeping track of all the closing } curly braces. I'll tell you, it is a nightmare. The alternative syntax is a personal preference, but helps readability.